# BizTalk runtime does not use imported XSD by schemalocation

Tags: xsd, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010, xml-validation

I'm converting a XML from one XSD to another by using BizTalk maps. I have "schemalocation" import in one XSD just like below

```
<xs:import schemaLocation=".\CurrencySchema.xsd" namespace="http://Biztalk.CurrencySchema" />
```

I built this solution which includes two schemas and one BizTalk map. After I GACed it, İ have added the DLL to BizTalk assembly. There is no problem on this side.

The problem is beginning when I sent the XML to BizTalk for converting. While validation of this XML BizTalk gets error just like below.

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: Type 'http://Biztalk.CurrencySchema:curType' is not declared.
```

I checked the BizTalk schemas and maps from BizTalk application. Two schemas and one map uploaded correctly to BizTalk administration console.

I think BizTalk doesn't import the referenced XSD on validation process. I don't understand why.
Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Is the namespace of the CurrencySchema.xsd the same as the namespace of your root schema? If so, you can include it instead of importing it. What if you validate the result xml in Visual Studio?

Comment: I have solved the problem. You have to add imported xsd to XmlDoceument object.

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(data);

            xdoc.Schemas.Add(schema);